# Unable to parse a date

Tags: ios, datetime, swift

I'm getting a datetime string in the following format back from a web service:

2014-08-22T15:00:00-04:00

Originally, I manually stripped the pieces out and rebuilt it to an NSDate variable.  The problem I ran into then was when I retrieved the day part of the date, hours 00 through 04 would give me the previous day.  Even when applying the local timezone to the date formatter, the printed value of the new date ended with +0000, which can't be right.

Anyway, I then found some code on apple's site in Ojbective-C and translated it into Swift:

```
    func userVisibleDateTimeStringForRFC3339DateTimeString(rfc3339DateTimeString: String) -> NSDate {

        let rfc3339DateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        let enUSPOSIXLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        rfc3339DateFormatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale
        rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
        let date = rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFromString(rfc3339DateTimeString)


        return date!
    }
```

(the original code produced a "user readable date string."  I just needed the date.

Now, it crashes on the return statement because date is nil, meaning it's not parsing that datetime string.

I've even tried simply:

```
let format="yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
var dateFmt = NSDateFormatter()

dateFmt.dateFormat = format

println(noaaDate)
let newreadableDate = dateFmt.dateFromString(noaaDate)
println(newreadableDate)
```

newreadableDate is nil

All I need is to convert that string into a date that will let me do proper day component comparisons later on.

Comment: If all you're really interested in is the date components it might be easier to just parse it yourself and use `NSDateComponents`

Comment: Now that you mention it, I've encountered an issue with that as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489969/date-comparison-or-timezone-not-set-properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't escape formatting characters, the 'Z' must not be escaped, it is a formatting syntax character. Only the 'T' must be escaped because it is a syntax character and should not be interpreted as one. The '-' and '=' are not syntax characters so they do not need to be escaped but can be.

From the docs: "ASCII letter from a to z and A to Z are reserved as syntax characters".
So any of the characters a-zA-Z are considered syntax characters unless they are escaped.

let format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

```
let noaaDate = "2014-08-22T15:00:00-04:00"
let format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

var dateFmt = NSDateFormatter()
dateFmt.dateFormat = format
let newreadableDate = dateFmt.dateFromString(noaaDate)
println(newreadableDate)
```

Output:

> Optional(2014-08-22 19:00:00 +0000)

Comment: You **should** escape '-' and ':' as well. see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: There is no need, they are not considered syntax characters, see the linked ICU document. There is a provision for potentially including '/' and ':' as syntax characters in the future but not '-'. Escaping them will work as well.

Comment: No need so far. According to the documentation, Apple follows `Unicode Technical Standard #35` not `ICU`. And `tr35-31` says: "In addition, certain ASCII punctuation characters may become variable in the future (for example, ":" being interpreted as the time separator and '/' as a date separator, and replaced by respective locale-sensitive characters in display)."