# Date comparison or timezone not set properly

Tags: ios, datetime, swift, timezone, nstimezone

I'm trying to do a simple comparison of dates with the intent of moving to another array index based on the day.

Though vastly more efficient than the code I was using, the following ([Unable to parse a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487740/unable-to-parse-a-date/25487835)) doesn't preserve the timezone offset:

```
let noaaDate = "2014-08-22T15:00:00-04:00"
let format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

var dateFmt = NSDateFormatter()
dateFmt.dateFormat = format
let newreadableDate = dateFmt.dateFromString(noaaDate)
println(newreadableDate)
```

Output:

```
Optional(2014-08-22 19:00:00 +0000)
```

When I add the following:

```
dateFmt.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()  // I've even tried defaultTimeZone
```

the output is the same.  Where this seems to become an issue is later on when I'm doing the following:

```
// FYI:  parseNOAADateTime is that code above        
var earliestTimeNS = parseNOAADateTime(earliestTime!) 
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: earliestTimeNS)
let dayZero = components.day

// stuff, like starting a loop
let tempDateTimeString = "2014-08-31T01:00:00-04:00"
let thisDateTime = parseNOAADateTime(tempDateTimeString!)
let tempDateTimeComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: thisDateTime)
let forecastIndex = tempDateTimeComponents.day - dayZero
```

Now, forecastIndex SHOULD be 6 because tempDateTimeComponents.day SHOULD be 31.  However, they're 5 and 30, respectively, meaning four hour's worth of data is ending up with the previous day's data.

Where am I messing up?

Thanks

Comment: `NSDate` has no timezone, it is always stored as seconds since the epoch.  `NSDateFormatter` has a concept of time zones, but when it creates an NSDate, that is always UTC/GMT.

Comment: `NSCalendar` does have a timezone property as well, which will convert the UTC time to the given timezone before the components are returned.  If you want to use the timezone from the date string though, you'll have to parse it out yourself.

Comment: Any idea why, then, the day component from the date is one less than it should be for the first four hours (like the example above)? When I retrieve the day component from that second datetime, it should be 31, yet I get 30.

Comment: Because the date time in the second example is 2100 on 8/30 in UTC.  The date formatter reads the timezone, (-400) and applies that to the time 01:00 8/31 - 4:00 is 21:00 8/30.  The Date formatter understands timezones.  The date is ALWAYS UTC.  When the date formatter is used to convert between NSDate and NSString it applies the time zone as appropriate.

Comment: That then goes back to my original concern:  When converting that datetime text to NSDate, the date and time stay the same and the -04:00 is replaced with +0000.  This happens even when I try to set the timezone (as above).  If, as you're suggesting, the value I'm getting from calendar.components.day is correct, then there's a failure in the creation of the NSDate.  Is there something I can do to correct this?

Comment: There's nothing "incorrect" it's a misconception about how things work.  When you convert a string time that has a timezone component, it applies the timezone offset to convert the time returned to UTC.  You can dig the timezone out of the string and apply it to the calendar yourself, or, if all you're interested in is the date (which seems to be the case) just truncate the string at the 'T' and convert it which will give you an NSDate with the correct date and a time of midnight.